# Get URL parameters inside custom module

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I've created a custom block like this:

```
class HelloBlock extends BlockBase implements BlockPluginInterface{

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    $config = $this->getConfiguration();
    $result = db_query('SELECT * FROM {test}');
    return array(
      '#theme' => 'world',
      '#test' => $result
    );
  }
}
```

And I now want to programmatically get some parameter from the URL.

For example:

If the URL is `http://localhost/drup/hello/5569` I want to get hold of the value `5569` inside my module.

I have tried `arg(1)` and `drupal_get_query_parameters()` but I got this error messages:

```
Call to undefined function `Drupal\hello\Plugin\Block\arg()`
```

and

```
Call to undefined function `Drupal\hello\Plugin\Block\drupal_get_query_parameters()`
```

How can I get the parameters?

Answer (score 21):

Use `\Drupal\Core\Routing;`:

```
$parameters = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameters();
```

The named parameters are available as

```
$value = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('slug_name_from_route');
```

Where 'slug_name_from_router' comes from your routing.yml path property

path: '/your/path/{slug_name_from_route}'

If you want the raw parameter without any [upcasting](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/parameters-in-routes/parameter-upcasting-in-routes) you can get

```
$value = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('slug_name_from_route');
```

Answer (score 18):

I used to get the parameter value from URL (localhost/check/myform?mob=89886665)

```
$param = \Drupal::request()->query->all();
```

And applied in my select Query

```
 $query = \Drupal::database()->select('profile_register', 'p1');
 $query->fields('p1');
 $query->condition('p1.mobileno', $edituseprof);
 $query->condition('publishstatus', 'no');
 $result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

But on multiple parameter value, i am now successful(**Ex:** http://10.163.14.41/multisite/check/myform?mob=89886665&id=1)

```
 $query = \Drupal::database()->select('profile_register', 'p1');
 $query->fields('p1');
 $query->condition('p1.mobileno', $edituseprof['mob']);
 $query->condition('p1.ids', $edituseprof['id']);
 $query->condition('publishstatus', 'no');
 $result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 7):

arg() is deprecated in drupal 8, however we can get values like arg() function does in drupal 7 & 6

```
$path = \Drupal::request()->getpathInfo();
$arg  = explode('/',$path);
print_r($arg); exit();
```

The output would be parameters in url except basepath or (baseurl),

```
Array
(
   [0] => 
   [1] => node
   [2] => add
)
```

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/2274705 says `$path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();`. But I don't see much of a difference actually.

Comment: Given that we are able to get named parameters values from request match, we shouldn't use arg and explode. The problem is that we will run into a lot of difficulty if we have to change URL structures later and insert additional path components.

Answer (score 6):

To get query parameter form the url, you can us the following.
If you have the url for example,

```
domainname.com/page?uid=123&num=452
```

To get **"uid"** from the url, use..

```
$uid = \Drupal::request()->query->get('uid');
```

To get **"num"** from the url, use..

```
$num = \Drupal::request()->query->get('num');
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$route_match = \Drupal::service('current_route_match');
$abc = $route_match->getParameter('node'); //node is refrence to what you have written in you routing file i.e: 

in something.routing.yml
entity.node.somepath:
  path: '/some/{node}/path'
```

I have used {node} as arg(1). And I can access it by using *->getParameter('node');

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 4):

If your url is like this below example

```
http://localhost/drupal/node/6666
```

Then you have to get the full url path by

```
$current_path = \Drupal::request()->getPathInfo();
```

then explode the path to get the arguments array.

```
$path_args = explode('/', $current_path);
```

Another example if value passed by a key in url like below where id contains the value

```
http://localhost/drupal?id=123
```

You can get the id by given drupal request

```
$id = \Drupal::request()->query->get('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the example of accessing URL parameters and passing them to a TWIG template,
I am considering you have already created your module and required files and suppose "/test?fn=admin" is your URL

1. In Your .module file implement hook_theme and define variables and template name (Make sure you replace "_" with "-" when creating the template file)

   ```
    function my_module_theme () {   
            return [
             'your_template_name' => [               
                'variables' => [
                    'first_name'    => NULL,
                 ],   
            ]; 
          }
   ```

Now create your controller and put below code in it.

```
 namespace Drupal\my_module\Controller;

 use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;


 class MyModule extends ControllerBase {

   public function content(Request $request) {

     return [
       '#theme' => 'my_template',
       '#first_name' => $request->query->get('fn'), //This is because the parameters are in $_GET, if you are accessing from $_POST then use "request" instead "query"
     ];
   }

 }
```

Now in your TWIG file which should be "my-template.html.twig" you can access this parameter as,

```
 <h3>First Name: {{ first_name }}</h3>
```

And its done. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The Drupal docs are great on this: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/parameters-in-routes

1. define your path variable in yaml

   ```
   example.name:
     path: '/example/{name}'
     ...
   ```
2. Add the variable in your method and use it

   ```
   <?php
   class ExampleController {  
     // ...
     public function content($name) {
       // Name is a string value.
       // Do something with $name.
     }
   }
   ?>
   ```